# Attempted installing Google Play Store, but ended up installing Android Market!

Tags: google-play-store, 2.3-gingerbread, android-emulator

As seen below, anything to do with Google Play is installed in the Android SDK in my Ubuntu.

[image]

In light of this SDK Extras set above which has the Licensing Library, it is perfectly legal to have Google Play in emulators created here (correct me if I am wrong). Google Play is a factory default. Yet, when an emulator instance is created (even for that matter, a Nexus with Google API (say 10)) Google Play isn't already there.

So, in an attempt to install Google Play the closest I got is using [this](http://piotrbuda.eu/2012/05/installing-google-play-on-android-emulator.html) guide, as per which, I downloaded `gapps-jb-20130307-signed.zip` (the ZIP file for Gingerbread 2.3.3) and unzipped it and just executed the adb commands in the script given at the very end.

What I ended up installing was the Android Market! Why?

Comment: Minor correction: it's not the ZIP for Gingerbread, but JellyBean -- as pointed out by the `-jb-` part in the file name. So its even more strange it should contain "Android Market" instead of "Google Play".

Comment: I downloaded the zip with `-gb-` in place of `-jb-`. Installed Google Repositories (screenshot above), once again to no avail.

Comment: On GB, it might still contain the "Market" app. But don't worry, it should automatically update itself to "Playstore" once you've configured your Google account and used it at least once.

Comment: Updates itself! Wow! I don't need to uninstall it then. Will wait and see. Thanks!

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do, yeah :) Give it a few days (usually, it doesn't take that long -- just start the "Market" app and browse a little, then exit it, have a drink, and when you try next it's called "Google Play"). Once it solved, feel free to answer your own question -- or add a comment if you prefer me doing so :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I browsed a bit on Android Market and then I pushed another file from the zip downloaded. It's named `MarketUpdater.apk`. That's what updates the Market to Play Store!

Tried starting from scratch and pushed market updater too! So it was Play Store right when it sat in.